# Can my AZB2C Authenticated Maui app display protected URL from Web Application without logging in again?

Tags: webview, maui, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application which uses Azure B2C authentication.  I also have a Maui app which uses Azure B2C auth, it calls protected API endpoints and works well. I would like the Maui app to display a URL from the web app in a WebView without the user being presented with a login screen from the web application once they are logged into the app. Is this possible?

I have tried displaying the url in a WebView with attached token from the login, and this doesn't work (not surprising).  The WebView simply displays the login for the web application.

Comment: Could you include more details like what code you tried and errors if any?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!